# Regeln der Typografie zum Beginn neuer Absätze

Tags: typography

Als Student ist mir diese Frage ziemlich peinlich. Hauptsächlich, weil solche Grundlagen als Schüler bereits verinnerlicht werden sollten:

Ich beschäftige mich in letzter Zeit mit dem wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten und benutze hierfür TeX als Textsatzsystem. Hier wird für jeden neuen Absatz ein Absatzeinzug verwendet.
Mein Problem ist jedoch, dass ich im erstellten Dokument ziemlich viele Absätze verwendet habe, die höchstens 1 Satz lang sind. Meines Erachtens liegt der Grund hierfür, dass ich während der Schulzeit nur nach dem Gefühl her neue Absätze begonnen habe. Im Studium darf ich mir das sicherlich nicht erlauben.

Meine Frage daher:
Wann sollte am besten ein neuer Absatz begonnen werden? Wie sieht das Ganze vor Beginn einer Aufzählung aus etc.?

Ein Beispiel ist im anderen Forum hinterlegt:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605340/rules-of-typography-on-starting-new-paragraphs

Comment: Bezieht sich die Frage auf wissenschaftliche Arbeiten oder auf Texte generell? Eine allgemeine Antwort ist da nämlich schwierig, außer dass ein Satz pro Absatz etwas wenig ist. Im Web gelten außerdem andere Regeln als in gedruckten Dokumenten.

Comment: Wenn ich jetzt sage, dass sich die Frage auf wissenschaftliche Arbeiten und Texte gernell bezieht, würde die Antwort wahrscheinlich aus den Rahmen fallen... deshalb bitte nur auf das Thema "wissenschaftliche Arbeiten" eingehen. Das entsprechende Dokument muss ausgedruckt werden.

Comment: Die Typographie hat das Ziel, das der Leser es möglichst leicht hat, den Text zu erfassen. Idealerweise fällt sie gar nicht auf. Wenn etwas komisch aussieht, dann hat man Ziel noch nicht erreicht. Bis auf ein paar orthotypographische Fehler, die man vermeiden muss, hilft es sich an "schönen" Büchern oder Artikeln zu orientieren.

Comment: @HaraldLichtenstein Das würde ja bedeuten, dass man möglichst viele Absätze verwenden sollte, sodass der Text für den Leser leicht zu erfassen ist, oder irre ich mich da?

Comment: @Schubladenzieher Wenn durch zusätzliche Absätze Sinneinheiten voneinander getrennt werden, nimmt die Lesbarkeit wieder ab. Außerdem verringert die Absatzinflation den Nutzen der sinnvollen Absätze, da die Übersichtlichkeit und somit der Beitrag zur Orientierung im Text verloren geht -- von der Ästhetik des typographischen Erscheinungsbildes mal ganz abgesehen. Das alles spricht gegen zu viele Absätze.

Comment: @Schubladenzieher Ich denke, dass ein Absatz eher einen Gedanken enthält, der erklärt werden soll. Man fasst ja auch Wörter in einem Satz zusammen, um etwas verständlich zu machen. Einzelne Wörter haben keine Bedeutung und können nicht verstanden werden. Nein, ich glaube nicht, dass möglichst viele Absätze das Ziel sind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es gibt keine festen Regeln, wann man einen Absatz machen sollte, bzw. wann nicht. Allerdings geht es um wissenschaftliches Schreiben, so dass man hier z.B. nicht den Fall hat, dass zwei Personen sich unterhalten und so immer wieder neue Absätze gemacht werden sollten.

Normalerweise macht man einen Absatz, wenn

- die Perspektive gewechselt wird (häufig im Roman)
- man eine neue Idee ansprechen will
- man eine Ergänzung zu etwas bereits gesagten schreiben will

Dass deine Absätze jeweils nur einen Satz umfassen finde ich etwas merkwürdig und ich frage mich, wie du es schaffst das derart zu zerpflücken ;) .

Die Uni Mannheim (Abteilung VWL) schreibt etwa in ihrer [Schreibberatung](https://www.vwl.uni-mannheim.de/media/Fakultaeten/vwl/Dokumente/Leitfaden_Absaetze.pdf)

> Grundregeln des Absatzschreibens: Viele Studierende definieren einen Absatz nach der Länge: Ein Absatz sollte demnach aus mindestens drei bis fünf Sätzen bestehen und nicht viel länger als eine halbe Seite sein. In der Tat ist dies eine gute Richtschnur; viel entscheidender ist jedoch der Inhalt: Ein Absatz elaboriert eine zentrale Idee, und diese zentrale Idee bestimmt den Aufbau und die Länge des Absatzes.
>
> Häufig, aber nicht immer, steht diese zentrale Idee im ersten Satz, dem sogenannten „topic sentence“. Im weiteren Verlauf wird diese Idee dann an Beispielen konkretisiert, mit Argumenten belegt oder anhand mehrerer Kriterien detailliert beschrieben. Ein „topic sentence“ in der VWL könnte etwa lauten: „Das Capital Asset Pricing Modell ist ein wichtiges Modell in der Finanzmarktökonomie.“ Im weiteren Verlauf könnten Sie...

Scribbr bezeichnet dies als [Kernsatz (Beispiel)](https://www.scribbr.de/wissenschaftliches-schreiben/abschnitte-und-absaetze/)

> Thema des Textes: Windenergie in den Niederlanden
>
> Thema des Absatzes: Positive Konsequenzen der Windenergie
>
> Frage, die beantwortet werden soll: Was ist der positive Effekt von Windenergie?
>
> Kernsatz: Die positive Konsequenz der Verwendung von Windenergie in den Niederlanden ist die reduzierte CO2 Ausschüttung.
>
> Gesamter Absatz:
> Das positive Resultat der Verwendung von Windenergie in den Niederlanden ist die reduzierte CO2-Ausschüttung. Weil das CO2 in den Regionen mit Windenergie effektiv genutzt wird, ist die Luft in diesen Regionen weniger verschmutzt. Die bessere Luft hat viele Vorteile für die Natur.

---

Da die Überschrift allerdings etwas von Typographie sagt, und dies eher Stilberatung und nicht Typographie ist, hier noch zwei wirkliche Typographie-Tipps, was Absätze angeht

1. Der erste Zeile eines neuen Absatzes steht nie alleine am Ende einer Seite. Dies wird als [Schusterjunge](https://www.typolexikon.de/schusterjunge/) bezeichnet. Hat man so einen Fall wird diese erste Zeile auf die neue Seite gezogen und die Seite davor ist um eine kürzer

> Die erste Zeile eines Absatzes bzw. die Headline darf niemals alleine am Ende der vorangehenden Kolumne stehen.

2. Die letzte Zeile eines Absatzes steht niemals alleine auf einer neuen Seite. Dies ist das [Hurenkind](https://www.typolexikon.de/hurenkind/) (manchmal auch Witwe). In so einem Fall zieht man mindestens eine Zeile des Absatzes mit auf die nächste Seite.

> Die letzte Zeile eines Absatzes darf niemals am Anfang einer neuen Kolumne stehen.

Merksatz: Ein Hurenkind weiß nicht, wo es herkommt, ein Schusterjunge nicht, wo er hingeht

Comment: +1 für Deine super Antwort! Vielleicht hätte ich hinzufügen sollen, dass es sich bei meinem Dokument um eine naturwissenschaftliche Zusammenfassung handelt. Wenn ich dann beispielsweise Folgendes schreibe: `Unter den signifikanten Ziffern versteht man [...].
Unter absoluter Unsicherheit wird [...] verstanden.` Müsste hier der Satz über die absoluter Unsicherheit als neuer Absatz verstanden werden, weil im Grunde eine neue Idee angesprochen wird? So zieht sich das Ganze halt über mein gesamtes Dokument...

Comment: @Schubladenzieher "weil im Grunde eine neue Idee angesprochen wird" Nicht wirklich. Es handelt sich doch eher um eine Aufzählung von Definitionen. In diesem konkreten Beispiel würde ich wahrscheinlich nicht mal Fließtext benutzen.

Comment: Um die angesprochenen "Kinder" kümmert sich TeX glücklicherweise normalerweise selbständig.

Comment: @HalvarF wenn man es denn aktiviert ^^. @ Schubladenzieher In so einem Fall und bei räumlicher Nähe könnte man könnte man damit einleiten, dass man zunächst einige Begriffe definieren oder näher erläutern will. Dadurch wäre ein Verbindung gegeben.

Comment: @mtwde Man muss es zuerst aktivieren? Wie muss ich denn da vorgehen?

Comment: Wie mein Professor mal halb im Ernst zu mir sagte: mindestens eine Idee pro Absatz, mindestens 3 Sätze pro Idee.

Comment: @Schubladenzieher \widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000 sollte das leisten.